# Android launching intents for one page on a site

Tags: php, android

I've built a little mobile web app for the town I live in which aggregates a lot of info and makes it readable. Lately, on my android phone browser, when I go to a certain page it asks me do I want to open it with Browser or MX Android Player. I've looked at the request headers in Chrome and I can't find anything wrong with it. I've had someone test this on an iphone and the issue doesn't happen. Any ideas?

The site in question is http://sligo.me

The page throwing errors is http://sligo.me/Events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your page. It rather has something to do with MX Android Player. Android allows its app to register for URLs to be handled through them. In this way if Chrome is installed on a phone and the user clicks on an URL the system will ask if it should use Chrome or Browser to open the URL. The user can now select a default app or make the choice every time she clicks on a URL.

An app can also register for some URL parts only. A good Twitter app would register for all URLs with the host Twitter and then display the content of that page inside the app.

I guess that MX Android Player registered for some URLs and the http://sligo.me/Events matches that filter. You could experiment a little bit and try to change the URL part that the filter matches. More information about this filtering can be found in the Documentation about [Intents and Intentfilters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html)

Comment: brilliant, thanks! I guess I can just pick a default and stop worrying about it so.